# Unable to change directory time stamp after using FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to change the time stamp of the directory after using `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` also.
My code snippet is as below

```
    int SetDirectoryTime(char *Path)
    {
        FILETIME ftCreate, ftAccess, ftWrite;
        Handle = CreateFile(Path, GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, NULL);

        if (Handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            //Unable to open directory
            return FALSE;
        }

        if (SetFileTime(Handle, &ftCreate, &ftAccess, &ftWrite) == 0)
        {
            //Unable to set directory time
            CloseHandle(Handle);
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
```

I was able to get a valid handle but the SetFileTime was returning Access denied.
I tried EnablePrivilege for `SE_BACKUP_NAME` and `SE_RESTORE_NAME` still I get access denied.

Answer (score 3):

As the MSDN page on [`SetFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) **explicitly documents** the handle to the file you want to set the time on **must** have the `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` privilege.

And your handle, quite clearly, doesn't.

So... there you have it.

Comment: After making FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTE i don't get anymore ACCESS DENIED. It won't change the time stamp of directory even.

Comment: Do you get another error perhaps? Do you specify *both* `FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES` and `FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in your `CreateFile` call?

Comment: Yes, I specified both FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES and FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS in createfile call

Answer (score 0):

```
const
  cWRITE_FILE_ATTIRIBUTES = $100;   // not defined in Delphi7                                                  

var
  cfAttributes    : dword;
  cfDesiredAccess : dword;
  cfShareMode     : dword;
  hndFile         : THandle;
  ftAccessed      : TFileTime;
  ftCreated       : TFileTime;
  ftModified      : TFileTime;

begin
  cfAttributes    := cWRITE_FILE_ATTIRIBUTES OR FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS;
  cfDesiredAccess := GENERIC_READ OR GENERIC_WRITE;
  cfShareMode     := FILE_SHARE_READ OR FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
  hndFile         := CreateFile(pchar(_FQFN),
                                cfDesiredAccess,
                                cfShareMode,
                                nil,
                                OPEN_EXISTING,
                                cfAttributes,
                                0);
  SetFileTime(hndFile, @ftCreated, @ftAccessed, @ftModified);
end;
```

This code works correctly under Delph7 to change the time stamps of a directory.  _FQFN is a path with trailing backslash.

Error checking is removed and formatted for clarity.